# Can't admin my server in Garry's Mod

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod

I created my server by SteamCMD and install the ULX, but when I entered my server by clicking Local Network and join my server and open ULX menu it shows the options that like i'm not the admin! can't force changing the map or gamemodes or anything! just voting to change like any user, so maybe that means i'm not the host of my server?
and I have a simple question, when I create a server by SteamCMD, should I see my addons I subscribed? just like when I play an offline server? or my addons aren't active in the dedicated server?

Thank you, please help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add yourself as an admin.

You can do this by writing "ulx adduser YOURUSERNAMEHERE Superadmin 1" to the server console.

Comment: I did that but it says "no target found or target has immunity"

Comment: @deadmanwalking78 if you have a complex name, you can just write a part of it. My name is "[TR] ardaozkal", but it works when I say write "ulx adduser arda Superadmin 1".

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works, but please could you answer my question? when I create a server by SteamCMD, should I see my addons I subscribed? just like when I play an offline server? or my addons aren't active in the dedicated server?

Comment: @deadmanwalking78 you should post that as another question, I'll try to answer if you do. Also, if this answered your question, hit the green accept arrow on my answer (so the bot won't bump the question etc.).